# Why do aircraft on a junk yard have blind windows (e.g. German "Landshut")?

Tags: windows

Today I saw a picture of the “Landshut” (named after a German city, pronounced *lund's hoot*, not *Land shut*). The aircraft [was hijacked in 1977](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lufthansa_Flight_181) and now rusts at the airport of Fortaleza (Brazil) since 2008. German enthusiasts wanted to transfer the plane back to Germany as it somehow and sadly became part of German history, and the [German government intends](https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/rettung-landshut-101.html) to do so as well.

[image: Landshut in Fortaleza (Brazil)]

([http://hessenschau.de/panorama/landshut-104~_t-1488105510615_v-16to9.jpg](http://hessenschau.de/panorama/landshut-104%7E_t-1488105510615_v-16to9.jpg))

([Source](http://hessenschau.de/gesellschaft/40-jahre-nach-mogadischu-kommt-die-landshut-nach-griesheim,landshut-nach-hessen-100.html))

I noticed the windows are blind. In an [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/35701/18733) to an other [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35665/18733) here I can also see a “retired” plane and Peter K. mentions the blind windows in a comment. This gave me the impression that all “retired” planes have blind windows.

Do the windows get blind simply because the planes are left on their own for years and wind, sun, etc. make them blind or **are they *made* blind on purpose?** If so, which purpose?

---

#### Addendum

After reading the good answers, I reviewed the video I [already linked](https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/rettung-landshut-101.html). This screenshot:

[image: Landshut from inside]

<sup>(Source: tagesthemen from Feb 23, 2017, 22:15h (German TV news magazine))</sup>

shows the cabin of the “Landshut” and it's clearly visible that the interior is removed and the windows are blanked from the inside and covered with grey foil. I just wanted to share this image.

Comment: They are put there on purpose, usually to protect the interior/windows from weather and sun. I'm trying to find an article on the process of mothballing an aircraft...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is this 777 with doors and windows covered?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25795/why-is-this-777-with-doors-and-windows-covered?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Assuming you're more familiar with German (thanks for the pronunciation guide for `Landshut`!) than English, I'd use the term `blanked` instead of `blind` for the window coverings - even if they simply pulled down the built in blinds to cover them. _/English.SE discussion_

Comment: At [Davis-Monthon AFB](http://www.airplaneboneyards.com/davis-monthan-afb-amarg-airplane-boneyard.htm) they go further then just blocking the windows. They encase entire aircraft in a tomb of "spraylat" to fight against the elements

Comment: @FreeMan You are right, I'm German and English is only my 2nd language. I believe you _blanked_ is the better term, but to my understanding that would imply that somebody has done something (namely blanking the windows), and that was actually my question. If I'm wrong, feel free to improve and edit my post. And thanks for pointing this out. I always appreciate it when someone fixes my English.

Comment: No worries, @PerlDuck, you're one up on me! I know English and just enough of a few other languages to sound pretentious and unintelligent. I do know the German `v`->`f` and `w`->`v` pronunciations, but that's about it. I'm glad you took the suggestion in the helpful manner in which it was intended.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

taken from [Business jet news](https://www.bjtonline.com/business-jet-news/mothballing-your-airplane)

> For outside storage, **cover windows and recognition/strobe lights with barrier material** and pay attention to atmospheric conditions, as humidity will accelerate corrosion. Make sure all control locks or control column gust locks are installed to prevent movement of flight control surfaces.
>   (emphasis mine)

One reason to protect the inside fabrics, plastics etc from the effects of discolouration from sunlight, as well as inhibit biological growth. Also without the coverings the temperature inside the aircraft will be significantly higher on sunny days see [Desert Usa](http://www.desertusa.com/arizona-desert/airplane-graveyards.html)

> [without protection] the interior could quickly heat up to 200 degrees Fahrenheit during hot summer days

Answer (score 9):

[image]
([photobucket.com](http://photobucket.com/gallery/user/LeoMuse747/media/cGF0aDovYWlybGluZXJzMDRfenBzdHhvamNxZWEuanBn)) Clearer view.

From the shadows it looks like they are covered from the inside / blinds closed. I couldn't find any article on [Plexiglas](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31423/when-airplanes-first-got-windows-what-material-was-used) turning blind/opaque when stored.

It serves the purpose of protecting the interior. Even if the seats and [sidewall covers](https://assets.catawiki.nl/assets/2015/11/17/2/c/a/2cafbc5a-8d39-11e5-929b-ca96581a9776.jpg) are removed, you still want to protect the structural frames from prolonged sunlight and heat buildup.

---

Related: [Why is this 777 with doors and windows covered?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25795/why-is-this-777-with-doors-and-windows-covered)